# Item not showing in agenda

Tags: org-mode

In my org mode file I have:

```
* TODO [#A] Call UPS 1 <2020-09-25 Fri>

* TODO [#A] Call UPS 2 <2020-09-25 Fri>

* TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 <2020-09-25 Fri .+1w>
```

But only:

`TODO [#A] Call UPS 3`

Shows up in the Agenda.

However, all 3 TODO's do show up in the Global TODO List.

I don't understand why, when all 3 TODO's have the same priority and the same date, that only the one with a repeating date shows up in the Agenda.

Any help is appreciated......

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The agenda looks towards the future, not the past: the third one shows because it is repeated, so it is shown for Oct 2.

Comment: Thank you NIckD once again. 
I feel like such a noob LOL. 
What threw me off is that the agenda does not show the timestamp of the third one, so I did not know it was showing it because it is in future.
I do have my agenda set to only show today. 
I guess the only way to show TODOs with a timestamp in the past is to give them a DEADLINE timestamp.
If you wish to provide your response as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: If you have the agenda set  to show just today, then it should not show any of them. How did you set it to just today? With a weekly agenda, the third one will show on Friday, Oct. 2 but not on any other day. Also, DEADLINE is *NOT* the way to show TODOs with a timestamp in the past. If you can describe what you are trying to do, I 'd be happy to provide an answer if I can, but ATM I don't understand the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that I have a file `foo.org` with the following contents:

```
* TODO [#A] Call UPS 1 <2020-09-25 Fri>

* TODO [#A] Call UPS 2 <2020-09-25 Fri>

* TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 <2020-09-25 Fri .+1w>
```

and this file is the only file in the agenda file list; and I use the default weekly agenda; and I have set up the agenda keybinding as the manual recommends (i.e. just the following in my init file, so that I don't get tripped up by other settings):

```el
(setq org-agenda-files '("/path/to/foo.org"))
(setq org-agenda-span 'week)

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)
```

and I start emacs and construct the agenda with `C-c a a`, then the agenda looks like this:

```
Week-agenda (W40):
Monday     28 September 2020 W40
Tuesday    29 September 2020
Wednesday  30 September 2020
Thursday    1 October 2020
Friday      2 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday    3 October 2020
Sunday      4 October 2020
```

with just the third item in the Friday, Oct 2 slot, as discussed in the comments. That item shows because it is in the future, whereas the others do not show because they are in the past.

If I instead make the agenda a daily agenda by changing the value of `org-agenda-span` in the init file:

```el
(setq org-agenda-span 'day)
```

I restart emacs, and get an agenda I see this:

```
Monday     28 September 2020 W40
```

That's it: none of them is for today's date, so nothing shows up.

If I make the agenda monthly with

```el
(setq org-agenda-span 'month)
```

restart emacs and show the agenda, I now see this (with most of the empty entries elided to save space):

```
Month-agenda (W40-W44):
Monday     28 September 2020 W40
...
Friday      2 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday    3 October 2020
...
Friday      9 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   10 October 2020
...
Friday     16 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   17 October 2020
...
Friday     23 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   24 October 2020
Sunday     25 October 2020
Monday     26 October 2020 W44
Tuesday    27 October 2020
```

with just the repeating entry showing every Friday.

Finally, if I make the monthly agenda start earlier so that it includes the 09/25 date by adding this to my init file:

```el
(setq org-agenda-start-day "-1w")
```

so that the monthly agenda starts one week before today, then restart emacs and get an agenda, I get this (again eliding most of the empty days to keep things short):

```
Month-agenda (W39-W43):
Monday     21 September 2020 W39
Tuesday    22 September 2020
...
Friday     25 September 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 1 
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 2 
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   26 September 2020
...
Friday      2 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday    3 October 2020
...
Friday      9 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   10 October 2020
...
Friday     16 October 2020
  foo:        TODO [#A] Call UPS 3 
Saturday   17 October 2020
...
```

Now all of them show up on Fri, Sept. 25 and the third, repeating one shows up every Friday after that.

You can also switch time frames interactively: get rid of the customizations except for the `org-agenda-files` one and restart emacs. Then `C-c a a` should give you a weekly agenda, as in the first display above. Pressing `b` moves the time frame back a week; pressing `f` moves forward a week (or a day or a month depending on `org-agenda-span`).

The [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html) is indispensable. For this particular subject, check the chapter on [Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html#Agenda-Views) and the section [Commands in the Agenda Buffer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html#Agenda-Commands) for all the keys that you can use in the agenda buffer to do various useful things.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just a quick note to say thank you NickD - it will take me a few days to process and try your answers......

Comment: I understand - take your time.

Comment: Hey NickD. First of all thank you so much for taking the time to provide such an extensive answer.

Comment: NickD you asked: If you have the agenda set to show just today, then it should not show any of them. How did you set it to just today? I do that with "(setq org-agenda-span 1)"

Comment: NickD: You asked what I would like to do - I am trying to create a personal planner and organizer and this is how I would like to use it:

Comment: Use org mode DEADLINE for things to do (TTD) for which an external organization imposes a deadline - eg a Credit card company will impose an external deadline to pay a credit card bill by a certain date. And this is repeating. Eg:  DEADLINE: <2020-10-05 Mon +1m>

Comment: Use just a timestamp or datestamp for TTD that need to be done but do not have an external deadline. Eg check bank statements once a month. The bank does not impose an external deadline. Eg: <2020-10-05 Mon +1m>

Comment: Use just a timestamp or datestamp for TTD onetime items that need to be done but do not have an external deadline. Eg Buy glasses <2020-09-25 Fri>

Comment: I setup a 1 day Agenda view to see (I thought) all overdue items without a deadline eg <2020-10-05 Mon +1m> and <2020-09-25 Fri> as well as items with a deadline eg DEADLINE: <2020-10-05 Mon +1m>

Comment: My agenda shows items with <2020-10-05 Mon +1m> and DEADLINE: <2020-10-05 Mon +1m> and not <2020-09-25 Fri>. This is my problem/question as originally stated - I would like to see the item with <2020-09-25 Fri>.

Comment: I thought it would not be good to have the agenda show eg 5 days into the past because I may have items that had a non deadline stamp of eg 10 days ago and then they would not show up in the past 5 days. My current understanding is that in order to show eg <2020-07-25 Fri> I would need to have the agenda show the last 2+ months which to me is impractical.

Comment: I have many TODOs that repeat daily. When I try (setq org-agenda-start-day "-1w") then each day in the past is full of items and those items are repeated in each past day, often shown twice in each day eg "Exercise in the evening. <2020-09-16 Wed 21:00 .+1d>" This forces the current day in the agenda to be shown WAY down the Agenda window (much down scrolling needed). For me this is not workable.

Comment: You probably want to have a regular daily/weekly agenda and then setup custom agenda views for the *other* things you want to do. See [Custom agenda views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html#Custom-Agenda-Views).

Comment: I do notice that TODOs with eg "<2020-09-25 Fri .+1d>" do show up in today's agenda even though their next date would also be in the past. So maybe one option is to make non-repeating non-deadline TODO's repeating just so they will show up in todays agenda.

Comment: No - they repeat daily, so they are in scope *every* day - their next day is today - always.

Comment: Thanks NickD I will check out Custom Agenda views. I am sorry to type so much info - I realize I am taking a lot of your time.....

Comment: non-repeating non-deadline TODO's DO show up in the Global TODO list so maybe I can filter for just them to show up there.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113517/discussion-between-nickd-and-ironfish).

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the above - my question is "How do I include a non-repeating TODO that has a plain date that is in the past, in today's view of the Agenda?"

I believe I found the answer - using a SCHEDULED date vs a plain (Not SCHEDULED nor DEADLINE) date makes a non-repeating item that has a date in the past show in today's Agenda view, with the agenda view showing only today (no past days). This is what I wanted. I have tested this quite a bit so I am pretty confident this will work. If anyone ever wants to test this in future, this may help:

```
* Testme01 - This does NOT show in Agenda for today (2020-09-29), nor in Global list of TODO's  <2020-09-28 Mon>

* Testme02 - This DOES show in Agenda for today (2020-09-29), but NOT in Global list of TODO's 
  SCHEDULED: <2020-09-28 Mon>
```

@NickD - thanks again for your time and attention and help to this and my other questions :) You are a great help to me and the community. PS I arrived late into our chat and I think by that time you had (understandably) left.

Comment: The chat does not have to be real-time: you can add things to it and I may (or may not) reply later. No guarantees! BTW, I'm not sure what question your answer addresses, but as long as you are happy, I'm happy. You should read the manual though.

Comment: Hey NickD, I added my question to the answer for clarity. I have been reading the manual and it was not clear to me. I also searched and searched for answers and did not find anything. Hence I asked the question. I don't just post every question here without diggin into things. I discovered my answer not by reading the manual (I did not find an answer) but thru trial and error of an org file.

Comment: Fair enough - I know that it's sometimes hard to find things in manuals. For the record, the section [Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling) says this in the explanationf ot the `SCHEDULED` keyword: "The headline is listed under the given date. In addition, a reminder that the scheduled date has passed is present in the compilation for today, until the entry is marked as done, i.e., the task is automatically forwarded until completed."

Comment: Ok, you obviously want to get into it. I am a retired professor and so I know a bit about documentation, instruction, help files, etc. Lets take a look at "a reminder that the scheduled date has passed is present in the compilation for today," 1) Reminder - what is a reminder? Is this defined anywhere in the page? In actuality, the HEADING and not some reminder of it, is listed. So the author assumes that because he knows what he means by a reminder, that anyone else reading this help page will know as well.

Comment: 2) "compilation for today" - What is a compilation in this case? Not defined on page. "The heading will be shown in the agenda for today" would have been understandable. For the record.

Comment: My interpretation of your comments is that 1) RTFM and hence 2) I am wasting people's time 3) When I point out that I find the manual difficult to understand, then "for the record" the exact spot where supposedly this is described, is pointed out to me. I have explained that I did RTFM, I hope I did not waste people's time, I hope as a matter of fact my question and answer will be helpful to some people in future, and that the description is for me not clear and IMHO poorly written.

Comment: Your comment has made me feel like I should not have asked and was dumb for not reading what you think I should have read. I don't think that is the point of "helping" people out. I also have some age related vision and hence reading problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "getting into it": I presume I upset you but I'm not sure why - I thought I was helping. In any case, you should send your input about the manual to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html): documentation improvements (and other improvements) are always welcome, particularly ones that make it easier for people to get into Org mode in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry you got that impression and that was not at all what I meant to convey.

Comment: You said "You should read the manual though." Then pointed out the page. Then pointed out the paragraph. That would be like me, as a professor, when a student asks me for help, telling him to read the textbook (not asking if he had) and then opening the text book to the page and paragraph he should have read and tapping my finger on it. The role of the helper is not to point out where the info is, and then telling someone to read it, anyone can find that, the role of the helper is to help understand the info.

Comment: Anyways, I would like to put this behind us....

Comment: One of the things that I try to do is give enough detail (as I hope you saw in my answer) and also give references so that people know where to find the information they perhaps missed. If you go check my answers, you will see that pattern (I hope). In any case, again I'm sorry I upset you but I certainly did not mean to. Hope you have a long and successful engagement with Org mode!

Comment: Hi NickD. I think with all the other answers you have given to my other questions and posts, you have been nothing but helpful and provided helpful answers. And I think I have indicated my sincere appreciation of that. But if you are not clear why I was upset I will try to explain. 1) In this case IMO to tell someone "You should read the manual though." when they already have is going to make people think 1) They are too dumb to understand the manual 2) Scolded for not reading it 3) Confused as to why they are being told to read the manual when they already have, etc.....

Comment: 2) Also, it is a massive and difficult to understand and error filled manaul. I think when you say "You should read the manual though." you think that anyone could simply find, read and understand the answer. I think that is an incorrect assumption. Please keep in mind you dont know who you are helping, they could be non-technical, not very good at English, have learning disabilities, brand new to org mode and so not familiar with the terminology used in the manual and so on.

Comment: 3) In a similar vein when you say :"For the record, the section Deadlines and Scheduling says this in the explanationf ot the SCHEDULED keyword: "The headline is listed under the given date. In addition, a reminder that the scheduled date has passed is present in the compilation for today, until the entry is marked as done, i.e., the task is automatically forwarded until completed."" - the same applies. I had already read it. I had already found the answer.

Comment: When someone is told to read something they already have read is going to make people think 1) They are too dumb to understand the section 2) Scolded for not reading it 3) Confused as to why they are being told to read the section when they already have, etc....."For the record" is language typically used to make sure something is documented - eg in a court case - eg in this case that it is documented that you are  telling me to read this in case there is a disagreement in future.  I found this kinda of confrontational....

Comment: My suggestion would be to say "Have you had a chance to refer to the manual? If not, it can be very helpful" and "Have you had a chance to read section such and such?" etc....

Comment: I could go on explaining why I was upset but I think this is sufficient. I hope this helps in understanding why I was upset....

Comment: It is very hard to try to communicate over a medium that is 1) very narrow-bandwidth and 2) does not allow one to see the "body language" of the other  person. And I don't pretend to be perfect: I have my own prejudices, preconceptions and accumulated tics and mannerisms that you do not know about (e.g. I often use "For  the record..." but I neven intend it prosecutorially). So again all I can do is apologize for the awkward way I expressed myself and hope to improve. I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Hi NickD. Sorry for my late reply. I do agree it is easy to misconstrue in this medium. I would also like to say that from my point of view an apology is not necessary.  It is very clear to me by all your answers and help both to myself in many questions and to others, that your only intention and achievement :) is to help others. I think you are building a great rep on Stackexchange which I admire and my feedback was intended to help build that, not to point fingers. I think in retrospect you meant "For the record" as in "For reference" and I am sorry if I misunderstood that.